# Token authentication

Tags: ruby, api, rest, authentication

Simple code

```
require 'net/http'

url = URI.parse('get json/other data here [link]')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}
puts res.body
```

Just wondering how to put an authentication token in php cURL i do it like this

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer xxx')); //Bearer token for authentication
```

Wondering how to do it for Ruby.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can simply add header:

```
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s)
req['Authorization'] = "Bearer xxx"
```

or shorter:

```
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s, {'Authorization' => 'Bearer vF9dft4qmT'})
```